# Why does my function return NULL while the same query gives me a result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function, sql-server-2019

When I run this query, I get an expected result, i.e. a single `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`:

```
select top 1 ec.NewValue from Events e
join EventChanges ec on e.Id = ec.EventId
where e.EntityChangedId = 'aceaea4b-e4d1-45ea-84f7-8ecda1a0b20e'
    and ec.FieldChanged = 'Company.CallFrequencyId'
    and e.EventDate <= '2022-07-11 15:32:00.0000000 +00:00'
order by e.EventDate desc
```

However, when I create a function containing the exact same query and call it, I get `NULL`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCallFrequencyIdAtDate](@companyId VARCHAR, @date DATETIME2)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS BEGIN
RETURN (
    select top 1 ec.NewValue from Events e
    join EventChanges ec on e.Id = ec.EventId
    where e.EntityChangedId = @companyId
        and ec.FieldChanged = 'Company.CallFrequencyId'
        and e.EventDate <= @date
    order by e.EventDate desc
)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.GetCallFrequencyIdAtDate('aceaea4b-e4d1-45ea-84f7-8ecda1a0b20e', '2022-07-11 15:32:00.0000000 +00:00')
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the return type to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring `@companyId` as `VARCHAR` is truncating the input to a single character.  Just using `VARCHAR` is essentially the same as using `VARCHAR(1)`.  Always specify the length of `VARCHAR` variables and columns.

But since you're using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` just use that for your variable

`DECLARE @companyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Make sure to also update your return type.

[image]

Comment: Considering that the input value appears to be a GUID, wouldn't `@companyId uniqueidentifier` make more sense?

Comment: @Larnu ...yes, of course.  Blindingly obvious.